# System.IO.FileLoadException When running Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I am currently building a ASP.NET 4 application.

I have a DLL called *CommupointServiceLibrary*. Each time that I try to run the web application I get the following error message.

> Could not load file or assembly 'CommupointServicesLibrary, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e3a9262f077d766f' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

The dll is .NET 3.5

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove reference of that dll and again add reference. Then you should able to do that.

Comment: Removing the reference and adding it again doesnt do the trick.

Comment: http://krishnabhargav.blogspot.in/2010/02/using-net-35-clr-20-dll-inside-visual.html This might help you